# Why we can omit some forces while applying linear momentum principle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, coordinate-systems, free-body-diagram

While applying linear momentum principle, namely that if force is zero linear momentum of the system is constant, in textbook they don't count for $N$ force from $M \to m.$ This force have component in x direction, so we can't say that $\overline F_x$ is zero. All surfaces are frictionless.

[image: Force diagram]

Explanation in book is like this: *"Because we are not trying to calculate each force, apply linear momentum principle so that N does not appear."*

Comment: that force prevents the mass $m$ from penetrating the mass $M$

Comment: They aren't "omit[ting]" the force.  They want you to rearrange the variables so it's not part of the answer, as well it shouldn't.

Comment: @Phoenix87 ok, force R prevents mass M from penetrating the Earth, but they include it in the picture.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft sorry, don't understand you, that variables? Could you write it as an answer with some more explanations?

Comment: Linear momentum of *what* is constant? Just $m$, or $m$ and $M$? Also, is there friction between the ground and the ramp?

Answer (score 0):

The $x$-direction can be defined to be parallel to the ramp (not left/right). If this choice is made, then the normal force is perpendicular to the ramp, i.e. $N_x=0$.

Comment: We have two normal forces here, not parallel.